# twisted IRCClient with a listentcp

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to make a simple IRC bot that also listens to another port for incoming data and relays that to an IRC channel.. I'm using the following as sample code for my bot

http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/

I'm getting stuck how I also add a listenTCP to be able to talk to the bot with the reactor. I can make it listen but not sure how to send it to the bot so the bot can msg the channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variation of a popular FAQ, [answered here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother).